# Mobile App Installs

Tags: mobile, sdk, installation, ads, facebook-ads-api

I am working on "FB Mobile App Installs" feature.
One of my clients for an iOS app created an ad with out creating a FB app ID.
The Ads Manager Look like this[image]

Now the client has asked me to configure Mobile App Installs.
After going through the documentation I created the FB app ID, then integrated the FB SDK in my app.

[image]

After integrating my iPhone app with FB add. I cant find the Mobile Installs in FB ad. I can't see any change in Mobile App Installs in "Ads Manager". However I can find this in FB app Insights like -

[image]
I have gone through all the documentations but couldn't quite understand what wrong I am doing?

Comment: Did they create new ads pointing to the Facebook app ID after it was created? If not, they're still just tracking clicks to the app store and can't track installs

Comment: yeah they didn't creat the FB app ID first. Now I have created it , but how to connect FB Mobile App Installs to that FB app ID?

Comment: An advertiser for the app needs to edit the ads or create new ads using Facebook's interface